# Rufus Scheduler: How to specify "on the first day of the month, at 8:00am"?

Tags: rufus-scheduler

I am trying to configure a schedule that uses the [rufus-scheduler gem](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler). I want to create a "once per month" schedule that runs at a specific time. I am trying to use the `every` syntax for defining it. How can I write this configuration so that it runs every month, on the first day, at 8:00am?

Comment: So what prevents you from using "cron"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation you link to, you'll notice that rufus-scheduler also has a cron method, here is how you would use it:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

s = Rufus::Scheduler.new

s.cron '0 8 1 * *' do
  puts "Hello, it's 8 am on the first day of the month"
end
```

To answer more squarely, rufus-scheduler "every" syntax doesn't let you specify something like "8am every first day of the month".

Comment: Yes, but that is using the cron syntax. How would you write it to use the "every" syntax?

Comment: You can't write it in the "every" syntax.